# "You're on the featured tab" and no selected tabs in vicinity

Tags: discussion, bug

I was browsing featured questions previously, but when I clicked on a tag that didn't have them, I ended up seeing "You're on the featured tab" message, while the tab was absent. And it's confusing! Where's the tab I'm currently on?

[image]

It should at least be there to allow me to quickly focus on the area where I should look for other tabs, because sometimes I look around the page for almost a minute trying to find where it all went wrong.

Comment: The tabs are in the top right: info, newest, frequent, etc. Click one of those. There is no "featured" tab for this tag because there are no featured questions.

Comment: @CodyGray I get it, but that, I believe, is not a proper approach to the design of those tabs (bad user experience, resulting in such questions).

Comment: Fair enough. I'm pretty sure it used to be worse. At least it says "You are on the Featured tab"...